# jQuery Mobile Page function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

```
 $(document).on("pageshow", "#mappage", function (event) {
    $("#doldur").append("<li> <label onclick='getBina(" 
                        + featuressokak[f].attributes.SOKAKID 
                        + ");'>" 
                        + featuressokak[f].attributes.SOKAKADI 
                        + "</label><div  onclick='findsokak(" + f + ");' style='float:right;width='20%''><img  src='img/map.png'   style='float:right;'/></div></li>");

    function getBina(sokakid) {}
 });
```

I wrote part of my code. I need to call function getBina inside on mappage function. But I got this error : uncaught ReferenceError: getBina is not defined. So when I wrote function getBina outside mappage function, logicically I got error. I must run on inside. how is it possible ?

my button code :

```
 var content = '<div class="adresbaslik">'+feature.attributes.ADI+'</div><p style="margin-top:-10px"></p><div class="fulladrespopup">'+mahalleadi+' MAHALLESİ '+sokfeature[0].attributes.SOKAKADI +' SOKAK NO:' + numfeature[0].attributes.KAPINO  +' '+ilceadi+'</div>' ;  
                                content = content + '<p style="margin-top:-10px"></p><div style="text-align: center ;"><a data-ajax="false" onclick="sendForm(&quot;'
                                +ilceadi+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                +mahalleadi+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                +sokfeature[0].attributes.SOKAKADI+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + numfeature[0].attributes.KAPINO+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + ilcegisID+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + mahallegisID+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + sokgetir[0].attributes.GIS_ID+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + numfeature[0].attributes.KAPINO+'&quot;,&quot;'
                                + feature+'&quot;'
                                +');" class="formgidin" >Bildirim</a></div>';
```

Comment: u need to keep getBina () out as its been exists when its called. rt now its scope within pageshow.

Comment: What error you got when you **wrote funtion getBina outside mappage function**?

Comment: i got no error funtion getBina outside mappage function. But i need to use it on scope of mappage scope because in function i hava variable for use on scope of mappage

Answer (score 0):

write the definition of the function then only it will remove the error "getBina is not defined". 
You can write the function globally or you can write function locally.